# Send multiple files using Email :: MIME in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, email, email-attachments, mime

I have a script to send emails with an embedded image and an html body, but when I try to send additional files, they are overwritten, this is my perl code

```
push @parts,
    Email::MIME->create(
         attributes => {
             content_type => $CtypeB,
             encoding     => $EncodingB,
             charset      => $CharsetB,
             },
         body => $BodyB,
        ),
    ;

  push @parts,
  Email::MIME->create(
        header_str=> [
            'Content-ID' => $Content_ID,
            ],
        attributes => {
            content_type => $CtypeF,
            encoding     => $EncodingF,
            'Content-Disposition' => $ContentD,
            filename=> $FilenameF,
            file => $FileF,
            },
        body => io($BodyF)->binary->all,
      );

    Email::MIME->create(
        header_str => [
            To => $Para,
            From => $De,
            Subject => $Asunto,
            Cc => $Cc,
            Bcc => $Bcc
            ],
        attributes => {
             content_type =>$CtypeH
        },
        parts => [@parts]
    ),
```

I assumed that being the elements of Email :: MIME created in arrangements these would be accommodated using push, however when I send the mail by adding several files, it is overwritten, that is, it sends the last attached file, any ideas or suggestions on what am I doing wrong ?, thanks.

Comment: Tip: Using `\@parts` instead of `[@parts]` avoids a needless copy

Comment: I don't see what you do with the return of the final create; could that be the problem?  Other than that, it looks ok.  Can you come up with a short runnable script that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: This is much simpler with [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer).

Answer (score 2):

You can attach multiple files like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::MIME;
my @parts;
push @parts, Email::MIME->create(
    attributes => {
        content_type => 'application/octet-stream',
        disposition => 'attachment',
        encoding => 'base64',
        name => 'foobar.bin',
    },
    body => "\1\2\3\4\5\6\7",
);
push @parts, Email::MIME->create(
    attributes => {
        content_type => 'text/html',
        disposition => 'attachment',
        encoding => 'quoted-printable',
        charset => 'UTF-8',
        name => 'foobar.html',
    },
    body_str => "<!DOCTYPE html><title>foo bar</title><p>foo</p><p>bar</p>",
);
my $message = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [
        To => 'you@example.com',
        From => 'me@example.com',
        Subject => 'foo bar',
    ],
    parts => \@parts,
);
print $message->as_string;
```

This produces the following message:

```
To: you@example.com
From: me@example.com
Subject: foo bar
Date: Mon, 9 Dec 2019 21:16:43 -0800
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="15759550030.CE8DFF428.4203"


--15759550030.CE8DFF428.4203
Date: Mon, 9 Dec 2019 21:16:43 -0800
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="foobar.bin"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

AQIDBAUGBw==

--15759550030.CE8DFF428.4203
Date: Mon, 9 Dec 2019 21:16:43 -0800
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"; name="foobar.html"
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html><title>foo bar</title><p>foo</p><p>bar</p>=

--15759550030.CE8DFF428.4203--
```